# When I Use VS2015 and Develop MVC3 Program, there have been some strange problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

There is a MVC3 program developed and compile using VS2012. It's OK and deployed is also OK.

But when I use VS2015 compile,https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMep6.png,not error，just warning。

but when deploy,It can't run.The error https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgr4k.png.The error text is

```
[A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7c2060f6\6145b34e\assembly\dl3\9036b7c7\fc8023c0_73fecb01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.DLL'.
```

So，I Know I should be good to learn English，  but now what should I do？

some Solution，but did not succeed： http:// www.cnblogs.com/shanyou/archive/2012/12/23/2830367.html

http:// www.cnblogs.com/highend/archive/2011/04/20/aspnet_mvc3_the_project_debug_in_mvc3source.html

This is my razor version:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Comment: I think you should look at the versions of your razor engine, You can update the razor version in the following directory ~/Views/web.config

Comment: thank you.  at the end of the question , i write my razor version.  so ?

Answer (score -1):

Mvc3 is supported till VS2010.I use VS2010SP1 btw.
You have to choose if you want to use Mvc3 or VS2015